# Upload large file to sharepoint site using Microsoft Graph via REST API

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to upload a file to a specific sharepoint site. In this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session) shows me how to upload a sample file to user's onedrive. But, in my case, I need to upload to sharepoint. I'm trying to use this endpoint:

```
POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

But show me this error response:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "itemNotFound",
    "message": "Item not found",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2022-05-08T23:15:29",
        "request-id": "ca4362ca-ff36-488c-80b1-9f82c3448cd5",
        "client-request-id": "ca4362ca-ff36-488c-80b1-9f82c3448cd5"
    }
}
```

This is cURL:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/items/test.txt/createUploadSession \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxx' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
  "description": "description",
  "fileSize": 4,
  "name": "test.txt"
}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to call endpoint which requires `itemId` but you send file name instead of `itemId`.

```
POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/items/{itemId}/createUploadSession
```

Another way is to specify the path to the file. The `item-path` must contain the name of the item that's specified in the request body.

```
POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/root:/{item-path}:/createUploadSession
// file system path using /drive/root:/path/to/file
POST /groups/{groupId}/drive/root:/path/to/test.txt:/createUploadSession
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, with `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/drive/root:/C:\Users\jose.sierraibanez\Desktop\test.txt:/createUploadSession` shows me the following error: `Resource not found for the segment 'root:'.`

Comment: @JoséSierra the path should be the path on the SharePoint not on your local PC

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of uploading a large file to SharePoint using graph API SDK [**Read more, step-by-step solutions**](https://www.stackoverflowtips.com/2022/06/microsoft-graph-api-upload-large-file.html)

```html
public async Task<void> Upload()
{
    
    string site = "<YOUR DOMAIN, REPLACE HERE>.sharepoint.com";
    string relativePath = "/sites/<YOUR SITE, REPLACE HERE>";

   var   _authProvider = _SetAuthToken();

    GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(_authProvider);

    Site s = await graphClient
        .Sites[site]
        .SiteWithPath(relativePath)
        .Request()
        .GetAsync();


    using (var fileStream =
        System
        .IO
        .File
        .OpenRead(
            @"myfile.txt"
        ))
    {
        var uploadSession = await graphClient
            .Sites[s.Id]
            .Drive
            .Root
            .ItemWithPath("sometext-1.txt")
            .CreateUploadSession()
            .Request()
            .PostAsync();

        // Max slice size must be a multiple of 320 KiB
        int maxSliceSize = 320 * 1024;
        var fileUploadTask =
            new LargeFileUploadTask<DriveItem>(uploadSession, fileStream,
                 maxSliceSize);

        var totalLength = fileStream.Length;
        // Create a callback that is invoked after each slice is uploaded
        IProgress<long> progress = new Progress<long>(prog => { });
        try
        {   // Upload the file
            var uploadResult = await fileUploadTask.UploadAsync(progress);

            //Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.UploadSucceeded ?
            //    $"Upload complete, item ID: {uploadResult.ItemResponse.Id}" :
            //    "Upload failed");
        }
        catch (ServiceException ex)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading: {ex.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```